# Parsing an RSS feed URL returns no results in a browser and CURL, but correct results are returned in an RSS feed reader

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed, php-curl

I'm trying to make a parser for a Kijiji RSS feed. The issue I'm having is that for some reason their RSS URL returns no results in a browser or in my script using CURL. However, if I parse the URL with a proper RSS Reader it works perfectly.

Here is an example URL `https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-poa/u1001906046` It should return the following returns as an RSS feed `https://www.kijiji.ca/o-tork-parts/1001906046`. The problem is that when I load the RSS URL in a browser it returns no ad listings. When I load the RSS URL at `https://codebeautify.org/rssviewer` I see all the results.

My initial thought that I must pass the proper `Accept` and `User-Agent` headers. I created my own RSS page to sniff out what headers `Code Beautify` passes. I got `Accept: */*` and a blank user agent. I used that with my code, but still getting the same page with no listings.

My code looks like this

```
$url = "https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-poa/u1001906046";

$headers = array(
    'Accept: */*',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fcjl9Lt.png — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wild guess: Your HTTPS libraries aren't up to date and its erroring as a result. Ensure your error reporting is turned up as high as possible. https://stackify.com/display-php-errors/

Comment: add `127.0.0.1 kijiji.ca` to `/etc/hosts` or change `$url = "https://127.0.0.1/rss-poa/u1001906046";` etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone — Why on earth would attempting to fetch the data from the OP's own computer instead of the computer *where the data exists* help?!

Comment: @Quentin thats not what im suggesting.. the issue sounds like a dns resolving issue. The OP is trying to curl back to self

Comment: @Quentin Now I'm confused even more. Try loading `https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-poa/u1001906046` in your browser. What do you get?

Comment: @JohnBaker — The same XML I get when I run your PHP.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone — If it's a DNS issue (which seems very unlikely), then the solution would be to put the IP address of `kijiji.ca` in `/etc/hosts`, not the loop back IP address.

Comment: Why make a round trip if your target is localhost lol

Comment: @Quentin This is what I get `https://i.imgur.com/ww4A38R.png`

Comment: @Quentin Looks like the issue is with the site itself. I uploaded the code to my server and it worked with no issues. This would make me guess that my IP got blocked for some reason, but it shouldn't have been and other RSS feed URLs work without issues e.g. `https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-poa/u1002385159`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone — The target isn't localhost!